# Are questions about collaborative development on-topic

Tags: discussion, scope

I haven't found our site's "mission statement" yet, so consider this another step in developing one.

Will we consider questions about collaborative development in general to be on-topic.

Although this type of development is common in many endeavours, it - and the problems it entails - is particularly relevant to Open Source development and all new developers need to come to terms with it.

Some topics I foresee:

- Choice of a VCS
- Questions such as:

  - [What exactly is a pull request](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/352/what-exactly-is-a-pull-request)
  - [how to keep open source projects up to date](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/370/how-to-keep-open-source-projects-up-to-date)
  - [how do I attract new programmers](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/54/how-do-i-attract-new-programmers)
  - [How do I stop people from opening questions ...](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/18/how-do-i-stop-people-from-opening-questions-in-the-issue-tracker)
- Questions about project structure
- Questions about dealing with contributors

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, *as long as* it is also about open source development. We can't have people coming along and asking us about developing their proprietary software merely because we allow collaborative development questions. There has to be some aspect of open source in there too.

Essentially, all this means is we just *don't close* collaborative development questions unless they're off-topic for some other reason.

Comment: Thanks for adding. I kinda missed the open source relationship. :)

Comment: How do you enforce the "as long as it is also about open source development" part of this? Proprietary software can be developed collaboratively within an organization.

Comment: @Andy: If there is no strong indication the question is about a proprietary project it cannot be distinguished. And it doesn't matter. Even if the asker uses it for proprietary development, most other readers who will benefit will use it in open-source development.

Comment: Not only that, but enforcement will come through flagging and review queues. And mods once we elect them.

Answer (score 7):

Collaborative development should be on-topic. As per the site baseline on Area 51:

> Open Source
>
> Beta Q&A site for people organizing, marketing or licensing open source development projects.

Collaborative development environments are a part of the organization of an open source project. By that, they should be on topic. The items in your list all fall under one of the three categories in this baseline.